# I want to update my android app in playstore that i made using basic for android

Tags: android

I just made my app using B4A and want to publish it in Play Store. And i want it to auto update whenever i made change in that app(new version). So my question is does i need to add the code in my app that checks for update or play store has feature that checks for new version and update automatically for the user.

Comment: No - No additional code ! Upload a new version APK to your Developer console & it will be available for users with Update option.

Answer (score 0):

The Play Store will periodically check for updates that you publish and prompt the user to install them.  You don't have to write any code to make that happen.